# Referencing in mongodb causes huge duplication of data

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I come from traditional sql background where as you use FK relationship when you want to reference something in table.

I start to work on a project in mongodb, the referencing is different, basically relational kind of referencing is obsolete in nosql, it uses key referencing technique. I found it's freaking when I have so many duplication of reference key in my collection (table). My colleage says don't worry, it's just how mongo work, it won't have performances issue because it's still fast.

eg. user_id and user_access is in every of my collection, says I have 500 over collection, every time I have to query those two key to do something..

Just want to verify is that true it won't break someday?